# Booting the CPU through JTAG debugger. How to exit from debug state and start from newly added PC address

Tags: debugging, arm, cortex-m, jtag, program-counter

I would like to use the DAP interface in the cortexm4 processor to download application code into a memory that can be accessed by a JTAG debugger. For now, I wanted to follow the following steps given on the ARM forum:

> For use cases such as a simple test case, where there is no desire to
> fully support continuation of normal execution after the test, and
> where writing to memory at address zero is cumbersome (for example,
> requiring Flash erase and reprogramming), a "quick and dirty"
> alternative exists; the already-fetched values from addresses 0x0 and
> 0x4 can be fully modified by the debugger through the DCRSR and DCRDR
> functions while the processor is halted in debug state. This requires
> the Main Stack Pointer to be written with a suitable "top of stack"
> address in RAM, the DebugReturnAddress (essentially the PC) to be
> written with the true address of the code entry point, the xPSR to be
> written with 0x01000000 (setting the EPSR.T bit), and, of course,
> downloading the executable test code into a suitable (writable and
> executable) memory region as pointed to by that DebugReturnAddress.

After I write into the PC register through the DCSCR and DCRDR registers with the address of where my code has been stored in memory, I wanted to know how to exit from the debug state and make sure that the CPU starts directly executing from the newly added PC address. Can i use the VECTRESET bit or will it clear the PC value to point to 0 again. Or do I just clear the DEBUGEN bit and disable the VECTOR_RESET_CATCH register to get out of debug state?

**How can I make my CPU start from the PC address I want to,after programming the PC value in debug state ?**

Comment: openocd works perfectly with these devices, did you look at how they do it?

Comment: and you have read the arm documentation?

Comment: @old_timer Yes. I've followed the steps as given in the document. I just wanted to confirm that after I update the PC value using the JTAG debugger, the processor will start from the modified PC value after deasserting the HALT signal. Also i couldn't find anything about changing the PC value . That's why I'm a little confused on how to proceed

Comment: you could not find how to resume after halt in openocd sources?  it is in there.